# Problem with sscanf not reading the 3 variables i want in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have an .txt  with "323,John of Sea,11.2" (ignore the ")

and i want to read this and then divide it into 3 variables like:  int number1 / char Name[100] / float number2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number1;
    float number2;
    char Name[100],Phrase[100];
    FILE *inf ;
    
    if((inf = fopen("Information.txt","r")) == NULL){
        printf("Erro!\n");
    }
    
    while (fgets(Phrase,100,inf) != NULL )
    {   
        sscanf(Phrase , "%d,%s,%f", &number1 , Name, &number2 ); 
        printf("%d  %s  %f \n", number1, Name, number2);   
    }
    
}
```

```
323,John of Sea,11.2
```

Well the problem is when i compile everthing it gives me 323  John  0.000000 an it should give me 323,John of Sea,11.2 i have tried many things but nothing seems to work.  IMPOTANT = It needs to be separeted in 3 varibels 1/ int 1 / chat vector .

Sorry for the english and if you can i would realy apreciate the help.

Comment: if you want to display the data with ',' then use this (commas between the data), printf("%d, %s,  %f \n", number1, Name, number2);  The code you've provide actually does what you wanted to do, heading of your question, to stored each data, separated by a comma, into different variables.

Comment: Use strtok to split the string on commas instead of using sscanf.

Comment: Blithley accepting that `sscanf()` has done what you hope, then having `printf()` use variables that may be uninitialized, you'd best **check** that the 3 variables were assigned... Don't let bad Input data crash your program...

Comment: Note: you check to see if opening your file worked. If it doesn't, you print an error, and then... go on and proceed to try to read from it anyway. I suspect you meant to return from `main` at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `%s` `scanf` format specifier will only match a single word of input. Therefore, instead of matching `John of Sea`, it will only match `John` and leave `of Sea` on the input stream.

If you want to read all characters up to (but not including) the comma, then you should use `%[^,]` instead of `%s`.

Also, you should always check the return value of `scanf` to verify that it was able to match all 3 arguments, before attempting to use these arguments.

Additionally, I recommend to limit the number of characters written to `Name`, so that if the input is too large to fit into `Name`, no [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) will occur (which may cause your program to crash). Since `Name` has a size of `100` characters, it has room for `99` normal characters plus the terminating null character. Therefore, I recommend to limit the number of matched characters to `99`, by using `%99[^,]` instead of `%[^,]`.

For the reasons stated above, I recommend that you change

```
sscanf(Phrase , "%d,%s,%f", &number1 , Name, &number2 );
```

to:

```
if ( sscanf( Phrase, "%d,%99[^,],%f", &number1, Name, &number2 ) != 3 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Parsing error!\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Note that you will have to additionally `#include <stdlib.h>` in order to be able to use `exit` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel: One more thing if you can, could you tell me what is the name of %[^,]  in C

Comment: @jvq3xd: The individual `scanf` conversion format specifiers do not have names. For a list of these specifiers, see [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) of `scanf`.